# Can not add new row to MS-Access 2000 table from .NET C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I am trying to make a simple winform application in which i could read/update and insert data to MS Access db table

When i run the application it reads data from MS Access db, and I am able to add new data or edit existing data, but those changes are not sent back to DB.

**Code in my Save button click event**

```
    Validate();
    myBindingSource.EndEdit();

    //myTableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(myDataSet.myTable); //this line was in generated code
    myTableAdapter.Update(myDataSet.myTable); //replaced previous row with this one, but with no effect
```

**When I press the "save" button**

I do not receive any error message, in the DataGridView, new row contains ID with -1 value and new row is not added to database

What could be the problem? What am I missing?

When I opened mdb file from MS Access 2007 it is possible to add a new row to this table

**This SO post seems to be about the same problem, but it does not help in my case**

[unable to add new row using datagridview using C# in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091803/unable-to-add-new-row-using-datagridview-using-c-sharp-in-winforms)

**[EDIT]**

I opened .xsd file and added Insert and Update Queries for myTable, but still that does not help - when i press Save button changes are not sent to the database

Comment: How are you loading the data from the MSAccess database?

Comment: 1) I have added Data source "Microsoft Access Databases file"(Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0) 2) in Form's load event i have myTableAdapter.Fill(myDataSet.myTable)

Comment: Are you sure that your dataset is updatable? You should check your connection's and dataset's parameters ...

Comment: I have 5 components below Winform - ..DataSet, ..BindingSource, ..TableAdapter, tableAdapterManager, ..BindingNavigator. This BindingSource component has parameter AllowNew==true. ..DataSet component has no parameters to make it Updatable or ReadOnly. Where can I find those parameters you ar talking about?

Comment: Did you define the query used in the TableAdapter or did you use the default (auto-generated) query?  Also, does the underlying db table have a primary key?

Comment: I used auto-generated query and underlying table has primary key (autonumber), and index for one more column. Update and Insert queries i added from .xsd file (mouse right click on table and choose Add->Query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution how to send data from Grid control to database, i hope it will help someone else as well (+added some usefull additional stuff)

**Here is my code**

```
//form level fields
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter;// = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

//choosing MS Access file 
        var ecgDbFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        ecgDbFile.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        ecgDbFile.Filter = @"MS Access files (*.mdb)|*.mdb";
        ecgDbFile.FilterIndex = 1;
        ecgDbFile.RestoreDirectory = true;

//creating connection
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + ecgDbFile.FileName;
        conn.Open();

//A nice way how to get a list of Data base's tables
        var restrictions = new string[4];
        restrictions[3] = "Table";
        userTableList = conn.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions);
//then loop through and you can get table names => userTableList.Rows[i][2].ToString()

//reading the data (in the grid)
        adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from "+TableName, conn);
        adapter.Fill(table);
        bSource.DataSource = table; //binding through bindingsource
        GridControl.DataSource = bSource; //actually it works fine if GridControl.DataSource is set to table directly as well...

//choose the appropriate trigger (some gridcontrol or button click event) to call for database updates
    private void GridControl_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //because of this OleDbCommandBuilder TableAdapter knows how to insert/update database
        OleDbCommandBuilder command = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
        adapter.Update(table);
    }
```